# Rotate object around global Y axis, ignoring its local rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, rotation

I have a player (green) and I'd like to make him rotate right or left.

This could be easily done by rotating on its local Y axis. The problem however is that the player may be rotated along its local X axis. Here is a sketch:

[image]

Here is the view from top:

[image]

I need to rotate the player along the red lines. I need to do this however no matter what rotation he currently has on the X axis. (The player is flying like superman, see first picture)

This problem would easily be solved by using a parent object but that is not possible with my current set up. 
The code I am currently using ends up with weird rotations as it rotates locally:

```
transform.Rotate (0,rotationY,0);
```

How would you rotate on global Y axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed to do was add a fourth `Space` parameter to the `Rotate()` method like so:

```
transform.Rotate (0, rotationY, 0, Space.World);
```